# Does Objective-C run code line by line?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm really new to programming Objective-C and programming in general, so forgive me if this is a super obvious question:

I'm wondering if Objective-C runs code line by line. What I mean by that is if it processes one line before moving onto another, or if it just runs the next line regardless of whether the previous line is finished or not.

For example,

```
int difference = number1 - number2;
if (difference < 0) {
    difference = difference + 10;
}
result = difference;
```

Say that `number1 = 3` and `number2 = 7`. When I run this code, will it go line by line and run the if block before line 5 and give me `result = 6`, or will it start running the if block and line 5 at the same time and give me `result = -4`?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Changed modulo to addition because of Obj-C quirk.

Comment: You should try running it and seeing what happens ;)

Comment: @MattS. It gave me -4. Does that mean that Obj-C runs all available lines at the same time?

Comment: @JamesSnook I mean that I tried running the code, and it gave me -4 instead of 6.

Comment: Perhaps try a bigger bottom number like `number2 = 17`.  Modulo isn't going to reverse your sign.

Comment: @BrianNickel It's still giving me -4 instead of 6.

Comment: -4 is equal to 6 mod 10. if you want the positive value then do `if (result < 0) result = 10 + result;`

Comment: @JamesSnook Never mind, changed OP to be addition instead of modulo. In math, -4 mod 10 ≡ 6, but apparently it's different in Obj-C o_O

Comment: @Eiko -4 mod 10 ≡ 6 in math, but I didn't know that in coding, modulo has a different definition of finding the remainder of a division operation. Sorry for my newbiness >.<

Comment: In both maths and computing the modulo operator can give negative or positive results. Depending on the problem the solver may choose to make the result either negative or positive or smallest absolute value in both subjects.

Comment: Do I see three lines on the "equal" there? ;-) But yeah, modulo in programming sometimes needs extra thought, and another though on the sign. And get used to bracket terms, especially when combined with bitwise operators, or be prepared to get frustrated.

Comment: python: `-4 % 10` prints `6`, (Objective-)C: `NSLog(@"%d", -4 % 10);` prints `-4`

Comment: @Eiko The three lines was likely intentional (it's mathematical notation for identical to), this is why the result of -4 is as correct as the result of 6 in maths. mod in the mathematical sense doesn't define either as correct rather it defines both as correct. Languages or compilers (if the language doesn't define it) are free to choose what is correct, in the case of C/ObjC I believe that it keeps the sign of the initial value.

Comment: @JamesSnook I guess "congruent modulo" is the mathematical keyword here. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as your thinking goes you may as well assume that it runs line by line.

In fact the compiler may put the code into a more efficient order (i.e. making sure that divisions aren't too close together, as this could make things slow). However even when the compiler does re-order things it makes sure that a result is calculated before it is needed. When you build the code in a fully optimised fashion (release mode) if you debug it you can see that the code has actually been re-ordered (the debugger jumps when you wouldn't expect it to). However as far as thinking about your code goes it's safe to assume that it runs it in the order you write it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to programming, all programming languages you will meet at the beginning of your learning will execute statements sequentially. It means that the next one happens only after the previous one ends. However, languages like Objective C are not line-oriented and what matters are not lines but statements, like assignment ending with semicolon! or if statement.